# Delimiter between domain and username in jenkins user is sometimes \, sometimes _ Why?

Tags: svn, jenkins, active-directory, sspi

I'm seeing some odd things with jenkins and sending mail.  For some users mail is sent to DOMAIN_username@company.com - some are fine.

Jenkins is using  AD for authentication - most users haven't actually logged into jenkins, the username comes from svn. 
my svn server is a windows2008 server using sspi to authenticate:

```
# authentication
AuthName "Subversion Authentication"
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
SSPIDomain COMPANY
SSPIOfferBasic On
Require valid-user
```

the best place to see it is in the `http://jenkins/job/job-name/1234/api/json` and look at culprits

```
"culprits":[
{"absoluteUrl":"http://jenkins/user/DOMAIN_asmith","fullName":"DOMAIN_asmith"},
{"absoluteUrl":"http://jenkins/user/DOMAIN_bobama","fullName":"DOMAIN\\bobama"}
]
```

Things are goign to work fine for bobama, but note asmith - the email will go to DOMAIN_asmith@company.com (which won't deliver)

If I look at the users configuration page `http://jenkins/user/DOMAIN_asmith/configure`

I see his email is actually listed as DOMAIN_asmith@company.com, bobama looks fine.

These values aren't coming from the user (neither has ever logged in to jenkins) - they're coming from AD by way of SVN.
I'm stuck - anyone point me in a better direction?

Comment: What is the asmith's fullname and e-mail address in AD account details?

Comment: agent smith
DOMAIN_asmith@company.com

Comment: I mean did you miss the matrix reference ;)?

Comment: Do you have two AD servers running on the same domain?  One could be older and reporting slightly different information.  We had a version of this problem when we were installing Google Apps with AD Password Syncing (it depended on which server a user authenticated against)

Comment: Also if a field is empty in AD, then Jenkins (or mod_ldap) could be populating it with a best guess

Comment: Does "SVN" mean something different than Apache Subversion?

Comment: Opps. terribly bad form to put a bounty and then go on vacation - thought I'd have better net access. will answer questions and put a bigger bounty up.

Comment: @bahrep  I got JXplorer and have been poking around in AD... things look the same

asmith has
displayName: Adam Smith
mail: asmith@company.com
mailNickname: asmith

bobama has:
display name: Barack Obama
mail: boboma@company.com
mailNickname: bobama

this is pretty far outside my area of expertise

Comment: What Jenkins version are you using?

Comment: Jenkins isn't too old 1.4.73, from early July 2012

Comment: Are you using the email-ext plugin or other plugins?

Comment: yes. on both counts.  I have email-ext 2.22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of Ideas:

- If you change to the directory where asmith was the last committer and you do `svn info .` What does the LastChanged Author say? "DOMAIN\asmith" or something else? What does it say for bobama?
- If the information going into Jenkins is really identical for all users, then the difference has to be inside Jenkins. I've been looking at the source of [MailAddressResolver](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/MailAddressResolver.java), which is just a dispatching class that invokes other [resolvers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+points#Extensionpoints-hudson.tasks.MailAddressResolver). However, I'm not sure which one is invoked in your configuration. There are fallback scenarios which try to guess the correct email if none of the resolvers succeeds. One that looks very interesting is ['MailAddressResolver problems with SVN & SSPI authentication'](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5164). This should actually replace 'DOMAIN_user@company.com' with 'DOMAIN\user@company.com'
- I've noticed logging in Jenkins' source. If the logs don't already indicate problems during the mail address resolution, you could [add more loggers](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) in the web interface.
- While going through the bug reports, I noticed ['E-mail to individuals who broke the build is sent to wrong address'](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13058). Which sounds a lot like the problem you're experiencing. And it's **unresolved**.

### Possible Workaround

While searching in all directions at once I discovered the [RegEx Email Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org//display/HUDSON/RegEx+Email+Plugin). It allows you to generate user email addresses from usernames using regular expressions. Maybe you could twist Jenkins' arm with this to get the mail format you need.

Comment: That was most excellent advice - I added a logger and understand what's going on.  I must admit i used the regex email plugin to fix up the mails.

Answer (score 1):

I've created [Additional Identities plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Additional+Identities+Plugin) for this purpose. Only a workaround until I found a better solution, but can help.